# how to understand the parallel="instances" in testng suite configure?

Tags: java, testng

parallel="instances":

> TestNG will run all the methods in the same instance in the same thread, but two methods on two different instances will be running in different threads.

how to understand this sentence?

Answer (score 3):

There's not a lot of context in that question but a quick google found the [source](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-tests).

Your test suite will create many *instances* of different classes and then run some tests on them. This particular parallel mode guarantees that whenever your test suite calls more than one method on any create instance this will be done in the same thread.

Why might this be important? Well, some functionality may depend on consistent threading, for example if they use `ThreadLocal`. Additionally, unless your instances are thread-safe allowing multiple threads to call methods on them could lead to interference.

If you're not sure what all this talk of thread safety is then you might not want to run your test suite in parallel. Or perhaps restrict it to `parallel="tests"` and make sure there's a clear separation between test tags.

Comment: @CedricBeust who decides how many instances of each class is created? (Please clarify the official documentation if possible)

Answer (score 3):

TestNG's default behavior is not to use parallel threads at all.

The `parallel` attribute sets **how** the suite will execute its methods when using parallel threads.

For clarity, consider a test class:

```
public class StuffTest {
    @Test
    public void doStuffTest() {
        // do your thing
    }
}
```

By default (no parallel):

- A new instance of `StuffTest` (say `st`) will be created at *each test run*; and
- Each method of `st` will be executed sequentially (the order depends on other settings).

When you use the `parallel` attribute, TestNG will use parallel threads to run the tests at the same time. <sup>(The value of `parallel` will set how those threads will deal with **test classes instances** and methods. [Check the docs for the possible options](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running).)</sup>

`parallel="instances"` means that if you have several instances of `StuffTest`(say `sa` and `sb`):

- All the methods of instance **`sa`** will be executed in the same thread (say thread **`ta`**).
- All the methods of instance **`sb`** will be executed in the same thread (say thread **`tb`**).
- And **`ta`** != **`tb`**.

Comment: Your answer is too vague because you fail to address how/when TestNG will instantiate multiple instances. If TestNG decides to instantiate one class per method then this execution model would be equivalent to `parallel="method"`.

Comment: @acdcjunior It is wrong to say that at each test run new instance of test class will be created. I for example take a test class, created a static variable(counter) and increment that variable in no parameter constructor of that class. This test class has three tests. When I ran it static variable is incremented only once for all tests i.e. counter=1 for all tests so that means only one instance is created of this test class for all three tests it has.